# How do I report an error in XCTest's setUp function?

Tags: swift, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

In my UI Tests, I want to call a remote endpoint to reset db status prior to running my UI Tests. This works great, but I want to make sure I'm catching any errors if the request fails. What I want to do is:

1. Stop the subsequent test from running (mark it as a failure)
2. Provide some log of what happened.

Here's some sample code that illustrates my point:

```
override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()

    var finished = false

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
        let request = Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/resetdb")
        request.response() {
            request, response, data, error in
            if let _ = error {
                let message = "Could not call remote helper -- \(response?.statusCode)"
                XCTFail(message)  // doesn't work
                debugPrint(message) // can't see this anywhere
            }
            finished = true
        }
    }

    while !finished {
        NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().runMode(NSDefaultRunLoopMode, beforeDate: NSDate.distantFuture())
    }
    app = XCUIApplication()
    app.launch()
}
```

Comment: What happens if you call `XCTFail()` inside the `setUp` body instead of in the block passed to `dispatch_async`?

Comment: search for xctest expectation on stackoverflow to find the answers.

Answer (score 6):

`setUp` is part of the test run, as is `tearDown`. Use regular XCTest assertions in either.

Comment: Interestingly, for me, failing an `XCTAssert` in an `override class func setUp()` (i.e. a @BeforeClass-type method) causes an internal failure in XCTest, because the 'test' variable isn't defined yet, so it skips all tests *and Xcode says they passed*. Apparently the assertions aren't always to be trusted.

Comment: Yes, I mean instance-level `setUp`. Thank you for clarifying that this isn't true for class-level `setUp`.

Comment: The problem with using XCTest assertions in the setUp method is that a failed assertion does not stop the test from running. A failed assertion marks the test as having failed but the test will continue running.

Comment: That is true, and no different from a regular failed assertion (which continues to run upon failure).

Comment: You need to set `self.continueAfterFailure` to `false` in the instance `setUp` method.